# How to enable a disabled button by clicking on same button in android java?

Tags: java, android

I want to disable button and enable it again by clicking on same button in android java app.

Comment: Please enter your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood something.  When a button is disabled, that means that all clicks on it will be ignore.  That would include a click to enable it.

In short, what you are asking for cannot work.

Now, you could implement a button that toggles between "on" and "off" states when you click it.  There is an existing control for that: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton

That may be what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

**What you want:**

You need a feature where once the `Button` is clicked it enters the disabled state and when clicked the next time it should come back to the active state.

**Problem:**

As @Stephen C pointed out, once the `Button` is disabled it can't be clicked again and brought back to the active state.

**Solution**

So instead of disabling the `Button`, we can just make the user feel that the `Button` is disabled.

**How:**

```
        short noOfClicks = 0; //declare it as top level state variable

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

               ++noOfClicks //this counts the number of times button is clicked  

               if( noOfClicks % 2 == 0 ){ //user has clicked the button from disable state

                   //do your work here 

                  mButton.setAlpha(1.0f); // this will bring back button to its original opacity

                 }else { //user has clicked the button from enabled state

                  //do your work here 

                     mButton.setAlpha(0.5f);// this will grey out the button(actually, it changes the opacity of the button and gives a disabled look to the button)   
                 }

            }
         });
```

**What Just Happened:**

Whenever the user click's the `Button`, `noOfClicks` will get incremented by one, the `if-else` check will determine whether the `Button` currently is in the abled or disabled state, depending on which we apply `setAplha()` method which controls the opacity of the `Button`.

**Conclusion:**

Honestly speaking we just used an ugly hack which provided a false sensation to the user that the `Button` gets disabled when he clicks it for the first time and gets enabled when he clicks it for the second time.